# Independent input feature z can be removed: if y=f(x+z,z), then y=g(x)?

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, machine-learning

Let $y\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{z}\in\mathbb{R}^p$ be *random variable* and *random vectors*. Assume $y=f(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{z},\mathbf{z})$ for some function $f$.
Is the following statement correct?
If $\mathbf{z}\perp \!\!\! \perp y$ and $\mathbf{z}\perp \!\!\! \perp\mathbf{x}$, where $\perp \!\!\! \perp$ means *statistical independence*, then there exists a function $g$ such that $y=f(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{z},\mathbf{z})=g(\mathbf{x})$.

Comment: @LSpice, independence here is in the probability sense.

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/429322/mathbfy-f-mathbfx-mathbfz-g-mathbfx-if-mathbfz-perp concerning same circle of ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple counter-example: take $p=1$, $x=+1$ or $x=-1$ with probability 1/2, $z=+1$ or $z=-1$ with probability 1/2, independently of $x$.

Define $y=xz$ [or, if you wish, $f(x+z,z)=(x+z)z-z^2$]; one has $y=+1$ or $-1$ with probability 1/2, independently of either $x$ or $z$; hence, there is no function $g(x)$ such that $y=g(x)$, although $z$ is independent of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @John, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/429285/independent-input-feature-x-can-be-removed-y-fxz-z-gx#comment1104423_429290), it is generally good form not to change the question after receiving an answer, but rather to ask a new question if necessary.

Comment: @John : What do you mean by "z is independent of x and y, respectively"? Which is it: (i) z is independent of (x,y) or (ii) z is independent of x and of y?

Comment: @IosifPinelis       Sorry, it seems the condition "z is independent of (x,y)" is better.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker, how about the new condition "z is independent of (x,y)"?

Comment: @John : Then I think the conjecture would be true. However, at this point I will not provide details on this. Since in your original comment you said you meant z to be independent of x and of y, separately, I strongly suggest you follow the advice by LSpice and edit your post according to your original comment .

Comment: @IosifPinelis yes, I’ve edited yesterday night.

Comment: @John : You edited it, not in accordance, but contrary to the advice of LSpice and contrary to your original comment (that you had meant z to be independent of x and of y, separately). I have now edited your post according to your original comment. Hopefully, you will keep it this way.

Comment: @IosifPinelis, I think the condition (i) is better, because Carlo has given a counter-example for condition (ii). Please see my reply to you 9 hours ago.

Comment: @John : I saw that reply of yours. Whether another condition is "better" or not, it is important that you stick to what you said originally and not invalidate a valid answer (Carlo Beenakker's in this case). So, please restore the original condition, that z is independent of x and of y, separately.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138844/discussion-between-john-and-iosif-pinelis).

Comment: @John : I do not engage in such chat.

Comment: @IosifPinelis   Ok, let me post another question. I'll restore it now.