# $\mathbf{y}=f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{z})=g(\mathbf{x})$ if $\mathbf{z}\perp \!\!\! \perp \{\mathbf{y},\mathbf{x}\}$ jointly?

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics

Let $\mathbf{y},\mathbf{x},\mathbf{z}$ are real-valued *random vectors* with possibly different dimensions. Assume $\mathbf{y}=f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{z})$ for some function $f$.
If $\mathbf{z} \perp\!\!\!\perp \{\mathbf{y},\mathbf{x}\}$ (i.e., $\mathbf{z}$ is *statistically* independent of $\mathbf{y}$ and $\mathbf{x}$ **jointly**), is it true that there exists a function $g$ such that $\mathbf{y}=f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{z})=g(\mathbf{x})$?

If it is not true, how about the simpler case: $y=f(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{z},\mathbf{z})=g(\mathbf{x})$ for $y\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{z}\in \mathbb{R}^p$?

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/429285/independent-input-feature-z-can-be-removed-if-y-fxz-z-then-y-gx concerning same circle of ideas. (John, when you post two questions so closely related, you really ought to link each to the other.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}$The answer is yes. According to standard convention, write $X,Y,Z$ in place of $\mathbf x,\mathbf y,\mathbf z$, respectively, reserving the corresponding lower-case letters $x,y,z$ for the corresponding values of $X,Y,Z$.

So, $Z$ is independent of $(X,Y)$. We also have $Y=f(X,Z)$ for some Borel function $f$. So, for any Borel sets $A,B,C$ in the respective spaces,
$$P(X\in A,f(X,Z)\in B,Z\in C) \\ 
=P(X\in A,f(X,Z)\in B)\,P(Z\in C). \tag{1}\label{1}$$
Since the independence of $Z$ from $(X,Y)$ implies the independence of $Z$ from $X$, we rewrite \eqref{1} as
$$\int_A P(X\in dx)P(f(x,Z)\in B,Z\in C)  \\ 
=\int_A P(X\in dx)P(f(x,Z)\in B)\,P(Z\in C); \tag{2}\label{2}$$
this rewriting holds by the Tonelli theorem, which implies that
$$\begin{aligned}Eh(X,Z)&=\iint P(X\in dx,Z\in dz) h(x,z) \\ 
&=\iint P(X\in dx)P(Z\in dz) h(x,z) \\ 
&=\int P(X\in dx)\int P(Z\in dz) h(x,z)\\ 
&=\int P(X\in dx)E h(x,Z)
\end{aligned}$$
for any nonnegative Borel function $h$ (provided that $X$ and $Z$ are independent). In our case, we apply this to $h(x,z)=1(x\in A,f(x,z)\in B,z\in C)$ on the left and to $h(x,z)=1(x\in A,f(x,z)\in B)$ on the right.

Since the Borel set $A$ in \eqref{2} is arbitrary, we see that
$$P(f_x(Z)\in B,Z\in C)  
=P(f_x(Z)\in B)\,P(Z\in C) \tag{3}\label{3}$$
for almost all (a.a.) $x$ (with respect to the probability measure that is the distribution of $X$), where $f_x(z):=f(x,z)$. Letting now $C=f_x^{-1}(B)$, we get
$$P(f_x(Z)\in B)  
=P(f_x(Z)\in B)^2\tag{4}\label{4}$$
and hence $P(f_x(Z)\in B)\in\{0,1\}$ for any (say) open ball $B$ and a.a. $x$. So, $P(f_x(Z)\in B)\in\{0,1\}$ for a.a. $x$ and all open balls $B$ of rational radii and rational coordinates of the centers -- at once (since there are only countable many such balls). So, for a.a. $x$, the support of the distribution of the random variable $f_x(Z)$ is a singleton set (by Lemma 1 below), so that for some real $g_x$
$$P(f(x,Z)\ne g_x)=P(f_x(Z)\ne g_x)=0.$$
So,
$$P(Y\ne g_X)=P(f(X,Z)\ne g_X)=\int P(X\in dx)P(f_x(Z)\ne g_x)=0.$$

Thus indeed, $Y=g_X$ almost surely.

---

**Lemma 1:** Let $V$ be a random vector in $\R^d$ such that $P(V\in B)\in\{0,1\}$ for all open balls $B$ in $\R^d$ of rational radius and rational coordinates of the center. Then the support $S_V$ of the distribution of $V$ is a singleton set.

*Proof:* Suppose that contrary: that there are two distinct points $u,v$ in $S_V$, so that the distance between $u$ and $v$ is $d>0$. Let $B_u$ and $B_v$ be the open balls centered at $u$ and $v$ of radii $d/4$, so that the shortest distance between $B_u$ and $B_v$ is $d/2>0$. Since $u,v$ are in $S_V$, we have $P(V\in B_u)>0$ and $P(V\in B_v)>0$. By the continuity of probability (or the Fatou lemma), there exist **disjoint** open balls $C_u$ and $C_v$ of rational radii and rational coordinates of the centers that are close enough to $B_u$ and $B_v$ so that $P(V\in C_u)>0$ and $P(V\in C_v)>0$.

Then
$$0<P(V\in C_u)\le1-P(V\in C_v)<1,$$
which contradicts the condition that $P(V\in C_u)\in\{0,1\}$. $\quad\Box$.

Comment: Could you please clarify how to go from (1) to (2)?  In particular, since the LHS of (2) differs from the RHS of (1), it seems like more than rewriting?

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee : I have detailed that. I do not know why you think that "the LHS of (2) differs from the RHS of (1)". They are equal to each other, as now shown in detail.

Comment: @IosifPinelis, why "the support of the distribution of the random variable () is a singleton set"? You meant: if $P(f_x(Z)\in B)=1$, then $B$ is a singleton set?

Comment: @John : I have detailed this as well.

Comment: @IosifPinelis I'd like to go a little bit further. I guess $Y=f(X,Z)=f(X,Z=z)$ for any fixed $z$.

Comment: @John : This is almost correct. It follows from the answer that $Y=f(X,z)$ almost surely for **almost** all $z$ (with respect to the probability measure that is the distribution of $Z$).

Comment: @IosifPinelis   You meant: $P(Y=f(X,Z=z))=1$ for any $z$?

Comment: @John : No, I said $P(Y=f(X,z))=1$ for **almost** all z (with respect to the probability measure that is the distribution of $Z$).

Comment: @IosifPinelis I am not so sure about your meaning "for almost all $z$ (with respect to the probability measure that is the distribution of $$)". If $Z$ is absolutely continuous, does it mean "for any $z$ such that $p(z)>0$, where $p()$ is the density function of $Z$"?

Comment: @John : No, that is not true -- because one can change the value of the density to $0$ at any one point without changing the distribution. What is true is this: There is a set $C$ such that $P(Z\in C)=1$ and $P(Y=f(X,z))=1$ for all $z\in C$. I suggest that you take (or review) a standard course in probability (based on measure theory).

Comment: @IosifPinelis, I am considering to practically choose a specific value $z$ to get $g(X)$ when $Z$ is absolutely continuous, because any single point value of $Z$ has probability zero. I am not willing to use $E_Z(f(X,Z))$.

Comment: @John : You cannot possibly do any better than what you got in my answer. Indeed, if you change the values of $(X,Z)$ **arbitrarily** on any set of probability $0$, then clearly your independence condition will still hold. So, you cannot have anything pointwise for all $z$ in any specific set $C$ of probability $1$. All you can say is that such a set $C$ exists.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple argument in the case $Y$ is scalar, which can be applied to each coordinate when $Y$ is a vector: The independence of $Z$ and $(X,Y)$ easily implies that $Y$ is conditionally independent of $Z$ given $X$. Hence,

$$\mathrm{Var}(Y|X)=\mathrm{Var}(Y|X,Z)=\mathrm{Var}(f(X,Z)|X,Z) = 0, \ \ a.s.$$

Thus $Y=\mathbb{E}[Y|X]$ a.s.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler proof using Shannon entropies. The hypothesis can be equivalently stated as 1. $H(Z|YX)=H(Z)$ and 2.  $H(Y|XZ)=0$. The thesis can be stated as $H(Y|X)=0$. Now,  we have that $H(ZY|X)=H(Z|X)+H(Y|XZ)=H(Z|X)$, by 2. On the other hand, $H(ZY|X)=H(Y|X)+H(Z|XY)=H(Y|X)+H(Z)$, by 1. Therefore, since conditioning does not increase entropy, we get that $H(Z)\geq H(Z|X)=H(Y|X)+H(Z)$, which implies $H(Y|X)=0$. Actually, one also gets that 1. and 2. imply that $H(Z|X)=H(Z)$, that is, $Z$ and $X$ are independent.